# SQL Query issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a little question. I'm studying for a database exam so I can't really test the queries that are asked in the questions. Suppose we have these tables:

```
PlaneModel = {id, number_seats}
Pilot = {id, name, telephone, birth_date}
Plane = {id, name, model}
Flight = {id, date, id_Plane, id_Pilot, duration, origin, destiny}
```

The exercise is: Build a query that will show the planes that were piloted by all the pilots existing.

What I've come up to is something like this:

```
select p.id from Plane p, Pilot pi, Flight f
where f.id = pi.id_Pilot and f.id_Plane = p.id
group by p.id
having f.id_Pilot in all (select id from Pilot);
```

But I'm not pretty sure if this works since I can't test it. Is it right? If not what do you suggest?

Comment: I suggest that you use proper `join` syntax.  If your instructor isn't teaching that, then take a better course.

Comment: it would be really useful for you to install a RDBMS on a computer to test your ideas with

Comment: You can tests things at www.sqlfiddle.com.

Comment: I use joins a lot but several students of the same course kept saying to use it like that.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I will use that to study then. Was unaware of that.

Comment: Well there's one lesson -- stop listening to those other students. They ought as a minimum be able to give you a technical rationale for their advice.

Comment: Could you axplain me what's the difference between joins and joining by where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query is not correct, because `having f.id_Pilot in all (select id from Pilot)` is *not* the right way to ask the "piloted by all pilots" question.

Instead, you could ask for the count of distinct pilots who piloted each plane is the same as the count of all known pilots. In addition, you should switch the syntax of your query to the ANSI SQL join syntax:

```
SELECT p.id
FROM Plane p
JOIN Flight f ON f.id_Plane = p.id
JOIN Pilot pi ON f.id = pi.id_Pilot
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT pi.id_Pilot) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Pilot)
```